# How to write two or more texts in tableview row and position them differently?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I have a UITableView and i want to right a text in a row which should be right aligned and another text which should be left aligned. And both of those texts should start with some space from border of the row. I don't want them to start with the border of the row. How can i do that?

[image]

I want to write text in every row which is left aligned and also a text which is right alighned.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show some image?

Comment: Sorry i wrote label by mistake. Its table's row.

Comment: You can take help of Custom cell and implement the same in your tableview and make it look as per your likings. There are several links available : my favorite are http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html and http://iphone.galloway.me.uk/iphone-sdktutorials/custom-uitableviewcell/ . hope that helps you.

Answer (score 2):

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath method just create a cell with 2 UILabels and give them the desired location. Small example:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
}    
  UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 20)];
  UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 10, 50, 20)];
  label1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
  label2.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
  //other labels customization and add them to your cell
  return cell;
}
```

did it without SDK nearby, so there might be some mistakes.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

UILabel is very limited in terms of styling and layout. Considering either using multiple layouts or CoreText.

Answer (score 1):

what you could do is subclass the label and over write its drawtextinrect function like so

```
@interface UILabelCustom : UILabel 

- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect;
@end


@implementation UILabelCustom

-(void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect{
    UIEdgeInsets insets = {5, 5, 5, 5};
    return [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets)];
}

@end
```

this would allow you to give a margin around the edges of the label
also you could create a uiview that contains 2 of this custom labels and left and right align them accordingly. using the uvview as a container for the 2 labels to position them as needed. i reckon that could create the effect you looking for

edit: just seen your edit was for table cell. you would need to create a custom cell as well as custom uilabel

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell {

}


@property (retain, nonatomic) UILabelCustom *label1,*label2;


@end

@implementation CustomCell

@synthesize label1, label2;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{

    [label1 release];
    [label2 release];


    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: You mean that i should add two labels in every cell and then position them like i want?

Comment: yeah you would position them once in the custom cell in IB or in code then when the table loads up that custom cell they will be where you want